# Faster Github download

Tags: github

Recently I don't know why GitHub download at dial-up speed and cause some plugin take more than half hour to download. The slow download only happen with GitHub. This cause huge trouble for our development team and result lots of time wasted.

So, is there a way to gain faster GitHub download like using cache or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing files you don't need, particularly binary files? If you can exclude all unneccessary images, .dlls or other executables from your source, this can have a significant impact since Git doesn't then need to search through lots of binary data to check for changes.